# Drupal won't validate required field when disabled

Tags: forms

I have a content type with required field in it.
If the field is disabled then Drupal won't verify it. (it is being verified if not disabled).
How can I verify that the field has a value even if it's disabled?

**More details:**

For some of the users I set the value by [Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) and disable the field (by implementing the hook `hook_form_alter`).

I still want to prevent the user from messing with the URL.
For example: he can take the "new content" link I've created for him that looks like:

```
/node/add/my_type?edit[field_to_set]=12
```

and remove the URL query:

```
/node/add/my_type
```

I thought that if he would do it, he won't be able to save the form because of the required field (which is disabled) - but Drupal won't verify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API docs of [_form_builder_handle_input_element](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/_form_builder_handle_input_element/7) disabled fields are ignored, you can try using #access instead.

You can try adding your own handler after that of prepopulate and check if a (valid) value is entered, if not redirect the user or display a message

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'MY_MODULE_prepopulate_after_build';
}

function MY_MODULE_prepopulate_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  // check #value
  if (empty($form['field_to_set'][0]['#value'])) {
    drupal_set_message ('You altered the URL', 'error');
    drupal_goto ();
  }
  // if #value is set, set #default_value as well
  if (empty($form['field_to_set']['und']['#default_value'])) {
    $form['field_to_set']['und']['#default_value'] = $form['field_to_set']['und']['#value']
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: I didn't got it. do you mean that I'll disable the field by myself or that I;ll verify the form by myself? also, please explain the code above (I'm novice with Drupal development). Thanks!

Comment: You can do both, it depends on if you want the user to see the field or not. #disabled still shows the field why #access hides it completely. How are you disabling the field right now?

Comment: For the code you have to create your own module, there's a tutorial at http://drupal.org/node/1074360

Comment: currently I disable the field in my own module, by: `$form['field_name']['und']['#disabled'] = TRUE;`

Comment: in the same module you can add the code above, or maybe check in the same function you're using now for #value and/or #default_value